# Compile snort 2.9.8.2 : ERROR! dnet header not found

Tags: 16.04, compiling, snort

I'm compiling Snort 2.9.8.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. When i run `./configure` following error is shown:

```
   ERROR!  dnet header not found, go get it from
   http://code.google.com/p/libdnet/ or use the --with-dnet-*
   options, if you have it installed in an unusual place
```

Installing `libdnet-dev` wasn't solve the problem. Is there this header file in official repository of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My SNORT installation problem was resolved by installing `libdumbnet-dev`:

```
apt-get install libdumbnet-dev
```

<sup>([source](https://nikko296.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/dnet-header-not-found-ubuntu/))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

dnet.h is in the linux headers, so install the build-essential package.
you can use apt-file search dnet.h to find the packages for files.

---

My error, just install the headers directly packages linux-headers and linux-headers-generic.  Those should get the headers for any kernel you install.

Comment: No change after installing `build-essential` package.